# How is Stackoverflow removing and adding &nbsp; to their { code }?

Tags: jquery

I'm having some fun with, copy/pasting code into textarea and then trying to make it look decent in a "pre" "/pre"... And of course I've looked at SO.

But I'm having some troubles with to much whitespace, so I'm trying to replace \t with some nbsp; but it's not getting.. like really pretty.

So I was wondering, how would be a nice way of doing this? How is SO doing it? Is it even able to do it in a decent way?

What I got right now is:

```
var content = $this.html()
                        .replace(/\t\t\t\t\t\t/g, "&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;")
                        .replace(/\t\t\t\t\t/g, "&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;")
                        .replace(/\t\t\t\t/g, "&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;")
                        .replace(/\t\t\t/g, "&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;")
                        .replace(/\t\t/g, "&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;")
                        .replace(/\t/g, "");
        $this.html(content);
```

Comment: I don't see the logic in your sequence of `.replace` calls (The second replace is never going to replace anything, because the first one already replaces these occurrences).

Comment: http://naspinski.net/post/Javascript-replaceAll-function.aspx

Comment: Agree with Rob. Me either. To what number of spaces does one tab correspond?

Comment: @Kolind Actually, your update didn't make it clear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you should use a jQuery syntax highlighter and let the plugin do the work for you.

http://alexgorbatchev.com/SyntaxHighlighter/

http://steamdev.com/snippet/